# Gnome Sound Interface has no permission to access audio control

Tags: gnome, pulseaudio

I looking for resolution of a disconnected sound interface in an Ubuntu 19.10 installation. I think it is related to a "remixer" audio package which I installed but can't locate anymore which has hooked itself between the pulse-audio and the systems interface and is now blocking access to the pulse-audio api.

Please let me know what you need to help me to solve the problem.

[The picture shows the sound interface which has no access to the pulse-audio server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk55y.png)

```
user@system:~$ echo autospawn = no >> ~/.config/pulse/client.conf  #use ~/.pulse/client.conf on Ubuntu <= 12.10
user@system:~$ killall pulseaudio
user@system:~$ LANG=C pulseaudio -vvvv --log-time=1 > ~/pulseverbose.log 2>&1
user@system:~$ cat pulseverbose.log 

    (   0.000|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not permitted
    (   0.000|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
    (   0.000|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] core-rtclock.c: Timer slack is set to 50 us.
    (   0.016|   0.016) D: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: RealtimeKit worked.
    (   0.016|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
    (   0.016|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 13.0
    (   0.016|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation host: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    (   0.016|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation CFLAGS: -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/pulseaudio-RQfNdi/pulseaudio-13.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -W -Wextra -pipe -Wno-long-long -Wno-overlength-strings -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wundef -Wformat=2 -Wlogical-op -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wformat-nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Winit-self -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wshadow -Wendif-labels -Wcast-align -Wstrict-aliasing -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option -fdiagnostics-color=auto
    (   0.016|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running on host: Linux x86_64 5.3.0-42-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 05:49:40 UTC 2020
    (   0.016|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Found 4 CPUs.
    (   0.016|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
    (   0.016|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compiled with Valgrind support: no
    (   0.016|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in valgrind mode: no
    (   0.017|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in VM: no
    (   0.017|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running from build tree: no
    (   0.017|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Optimized build: yes
    (   0.017|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: FASTPATH defined, only fast path asserts disabled.
    (   0.018|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is f029a1542d5d4b919dbe929844ce5c73.
    (   0.018|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
    (   0.018|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/timotheus/.config/pulse.
    (   0.018|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-13.0/modules.
    (   0.018|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
    (   0.018|   0.000) E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
    (   0.018|   0.000) E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.


user@system:~$ pulseaudio --system
N: [pulseaudio] main.c: System mode refused for non-root user. Only starting the D-Bus server lookup service.
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
user@system:~$ sudo pulseaudio --system
W: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode, but --disallow-exit not set.
W: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode, but --disallow-module-loading not set.
N: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode, forcibly disabling SHM mode.
N: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode, forcibly disabling exit idle time.
W: [pulseaudio] main.c: OK, so you are running PA in system mode. Please make sure that you actually do want to do that.
W: [pulseaudio] main.c: Please read http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/WhatIsWrongWithSystemWide/ for an explanation why system mode is usually a bad idea.
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/var/run/pulse/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authentication key '/var/run/pulse/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/var/run/pulse/.pulse-cookie': No such file or directory
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authentication key '/var/run/pulse/.pulse-cookie': No such file or directory
W: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Denied access to client with invalid authentication data.
W: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Denied access to client with invalid authentication data.
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the config files, forced to redeploy standard cfg which solved the problem.